# Permission denied accessing /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock from nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a node app that writes to the mongodb socket. However upon starting the node app I get the error:

```
MongoServerSelectionError: connect EACCES /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock\n
```

The node app is running under user X while the `/tmp/mongodb-27017.sock` file is only writable for user `mongodb`. Now changing permissions for `/tmp/mongodb-27017.sock` doesn't make much sense because mongod seems to recreate that socket file every time it restarts and with that it resets the permissions. I don't want to run my node app under the mongodb user. What is the normal way of letting node write to the mongodb socket?

**Some details:**

I run mongod as a service. I start the service with:

```
sudo systemctl start mongod.service
```

When the service is started, mongod creates the `/tmp/mongodb-27017.sock` file. The permissions of that file are:

```
srwx------ 1 mongodb mongodb 0 dec  9 13:00 /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
```

The permissions of my /tmp directory are:

```
drwxrwxrwt  28 root root       4096 dec  9 14:10 tmp
```

The connectionUri that I use to connect to mongo is:

```
mongodb://%2Ftmp%2Fmongodb-27017.sock
```

I am running mongodb v4.0.21

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mongod` takes the  `--filePermissions 0666` option to set the socket file permissions to the desired value.

There is most likely an equivalent option that can be set in the configuration file.

Comment: Ah works perfectly. I guess i need to practice my searching skills. All the solutions i found online didn't work for me but none mentioned this option.

Comment: Due to the size of reference pages for things like mongod arguments the information there is in fact often not indexed properly/found by search engines.

Answer (score 0):

Consider editing `/etc/mongd.conf`, so you can keep the default service file.

```
# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1  # Enter 0.0.0.0,:: to bind to all IPv4 and IPv6 addresses or, alternatively, use the net.bindIpAll setting.
  unixDomainSocket:
    enabled: true
    pathPrefix: /tmp
    filePermissions: 0666
```